# Performance and speed of animation is very slow after many colours selection

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I made an [animation](http://utilaje-neamt.ro/demo/) using html canvas and a colour picker from where you can change the two colour of the animation but if I change the colours several times my animation is playing very slow. How can  fix that?

```js
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;
var colorArray = ["#f4ed94", "#eef5db", "#c7efcf", "#a9d18e", "#78cbcf",'
  "#5eb3d6", "#bdd7ee", "#af90a9", "#ffc7df", "#ff5a5f", "#e88873",
  "#c4c4c4", "#ffffff", "#6e6460", "#464647"];

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  handleComplete("", "");
}

  //for Giftbox 
  //When Giftbox color change slider is dragged

function giftRangeChange(value) {
  var newValue = parseInt(value);
  handleComplete(colorArray[newValue], "");
}

  //When Giftbox color box is clicked

function giftColourClick(value) {
  handleComplete(colorArray[value], "");
  console.log(document.getElementById("gift-range").value);
  document.getElementById("gift-range").value = value;
}

  //for ribbon 
  //When ribbon color change slider is dragged

function ribbonRangeChange(value) {
  var newValue = parseInt(value);
  handleComplete("", colorArray[newValue]);
}

  //When ribbon color box is clicked

function ribbonColourClick(value) {
  handleComplete("", colorArray[value]);
  document.getElementById("ribbon-range").value = value;
}

function handleComplete(box, ribbon) {
  if (box !== "") {
    lib.properties.boxColor = box;
  }
  if (ribbon !== "") {
    lib.properties.ribbonColor = ribbon;
  }

  exportRoot = new lib.gifbox();

  stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
  stage.addChild(exportRoot);
  stage.enableMouseOver();

  createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);

  (function(isResp, respDim, isScale, scaleType) {
    var lastW, lastH, lastS = 1;
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
    resizeCanvas();

    function resizeCanvas() {
      var w = lib.properties.width,
        h = lib.properties.height;
      var iw = window.innerWidth,
        ih = window.innerHeight;
      var pRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
        xRatio = iw / w,
        yRatio = ih / h,
        sRatio = 1;

      if (isResp) {
        if ((respDim == 'width' && lastW == iw) || (respDim == 'height' && lastH == ih)) {
          sRatio = lastS;
        } else if (!isScale) {
          if (iw < w || ih < h)
            sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);
        } else if (scaleType == 1) {
          sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);
        } else if (scaleType == 2) {
          sRatio = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);
        }
      }
      canvas.width = w * pRatio * sRatio;
      canvas.height = h * pRatio * sRatio;
      canvas.style.width = w * sRatio + 'px';
      canvas.style.height = h * sRatio + 'px';
      stage.scaleX = pRatio * sRatio;
      stage.scaleY = pRatio * sRatio;
      lastW = iw;
      lastH = ih;
      lastS = sRatio;
    }
  })(false, 'both', false, 1);
}
```

[enter link description here](http://utilaje-neamt.ro/demo/)

Comment: Every time you call `handleComplete()`, you add a redundant `resizeCanvas` event handler to the `resize` event of `window`. These are *all* going to fire on a `resize` event. This is likely the problem. Why not just add it once when the script loads?

Comment: Works fine for me on my firefox 48.0

Comment: A lot of the code in your `handleComplete()` should only run once during `init()`. Especially the `addEventListener()` calls.

Comment: I need the resizeCanvas because every time I call the event handler the animation should be resized. Also handleComplete() it's called every time I update the colour.

Comment: You call handleComplete in all the click and drag events(giftRangeChange,giftColourClick,ribbonRangeChange,ribbonColourClick). You just pile up huge amount of redundant event handlers, each of which will fire many times for the same event. Event handlers should only be set once on page load.

Comment: Also, instead of responding to the resize events as the user is incrementally resizing (== many events), you can [debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) the resize function so that it's code is called only when the user is finished resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix that. I just edited the function handleComplete(box, ribbon) using the removeEventListener and after that clearing the stage and so I deleted previous colour values. Thanks for the other solutions.

```js
function handleComplete(box, ribbon) {
   
                if (box !== "") {
                    lib.properties.boxColor = box;
                }
                if (ribbon !== "") {
                    lib.properties.ribbonColor = ribbon;
                }
    
createjs.Ticker.removeEventListener("tick", stage);
                exportRoot = new lib.gifbox();

                stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.clear();
      
    
                stage.addChild(exportRoot);
                stage.enableMouseOver();
                createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
                createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
```